# Ubuntu 19.10 cannot see intel HDMI sound output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have "FOXCONN NanoPC AT-5250 Intel Atom D2550" hooked up to a monitor SAMSUNG SyncMaster T240 HD. Monitor is displaying desktop perfectly.
But I don't have choice to output sound to monitor - I have only two choices internal speaker (works) on S/PDIF output (didn't test).

I tried all help that is available on net (disabling pulseaudio, trying sending file direct), to no success.

I have idea that my error is in line in "dmsg":

```
     snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: Unknown ELD version 1
```

Looking at output

```
# cat /proc/asound/card0/eld#0.0
monitor_present 1
eld_valid 0
```

After decoding EDIT using `edid-decode` I got `EDID version: 1.3`

Logs from tools above and debug using `aplay` [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XUWPU0qP)

Log from `alsa-info` [alsa-project.org](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=bd5e8e9d80dd61305d22a80d87b30dd43e46bde3)

Comment: I have same issue on Ubuntu 16.04